# Validate the name of objects in the creation of stored procedures in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

When I execute the command below no SQL SERVER 2017:

```
Create or Alter Procedure stp_Teste01 
as 
select name, type_desc  from sys.objectsx
go
```

SQL SERVER does not validate if the SYS.OBJECTSX object exists. Only when I run the procedure that SQL Server presents the error message.

```
EXECUTE STP_TESTE01
GO
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure stp_Teste01, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 11]
Invalid object name 'sys.objectsX'.
```

Why does it not validate at the creation stage of the stored procedure?

If you place the name of the TYPE_DESCX column, SQL Server displays the error message.

```
Create or Alter Procedure stp_Teste01 
as 
select name, type_descX  from sys.objects
go

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure stp_Teste01, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 5]
Invalid column name 'type_descX'.
```

Is it not in the ALGEBRIZER phase that SQL Server validates the existence of objects in the database and the creation of the procedure does not execute the PARSE and ALGEBRIZER phase?

Comment: See this answer about [Deferred Name Resolution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/187027/60085)

Comment: thank you Scott Hodgin.